# Why can't I ping herokuapp

Tags: heroku, ping

I have an application running on heroku, say `my-app.herokuapp.com`. However, if I type

```
ping -c 10 my-app.herokuapp.com
```

in Mac terminal, it says `Request timeout`, though the app is running, I can open it in my browser.

Why is that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ping uses a different protocol vs opening it in a browser. Ping uses ICMP whereas your browser will be using TCP. It would seem Heroku simply block the ICMP protocol which is fairly common as it can be abused (try pinging www.microsoft.com also)

Comment: Ok, thanks... how can I measure the time it takes to access my app? Send HEAD request over HTTP with cURL?

Comment: I would suggest using NewRelic - it's able to measure server side responses and client side also - it's a free addon too for the basic version.