# Uptime Robot: ping heroku app always down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, uptime-monitoring

In order to fasten loading of my app on Heroku, I've seen that I need to ping it at least once per hour. This is the config I've set on Uptime Robot:

IP(or Host) : appname.heroku.com
Monitoring Interval:5/minute.

Can you please tell me why Uptime is always showing:
Current status: Down

Thanks

Comment: No, I can't. Can you please edit your question and put in more information? What monitor type did you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I ping herokuapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505192/why-cant-i-ping-herokuapp)

Answer (score 18):

I know its been 5 years and maybe now you're married and have 5 kids but to make it work you have to set monitor type to `Http(s)` instead of standard `Ping`. And just paste the full https url there and you're good to go.