# I can access my heroku free subdomain site via a browser, but I can't ping to it in the terminal

Tags: heroku, subdomain, ping, pythonanywhere, openai-api

I have this site at [heroku](https://doc-hero.herokuapp.com/) that I am trying to ping. 
 It says
`Ping request could not find host https://doc-hero.herokuapp.com/. Please check the name and try again.`
even though I can still open the site on a browser. I thought it was an issue with heroku so I hosted it again on [pythonanywhere](http://bosireal.pythonanywhere.com/) but it still won't ping.
I'm sure there is a simple explanation for this but I tried Google and still no luck.

Is there a way I can get it to ping?

You might be wondering why I want it to do that when I can still browse to it. Well, it's because I need it to be visible to Open AI so that it can access some documents over there.

Comment: You will get the answer here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505192/why-cant-i-ping-herokuapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove https:// prefix. ping is a different protocol and requires DNS only not protocol prefix.
2. heroku server still will probably not answer ping request as it is not required to.